# $timeout in AngularJs isnt working well

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I use $timeout function to hide div after 4 seconds when click on it.

it works well, but after I do some other actions in my site, it get slow, and happen after 8 - 10 seconds instead of 4.

this is my code :

```
$scope.layout.rightPanel.InputDataTimeout = $timeout(function () {
   $scope.layout.rightPanel.InputDataMode = !$scope.layout.rightPanel.InputDataMode;
}, 4000);
```

Comment: What sort of actions? And do you really need to put the timeout in $scope ?

Comment: I call to other functions that do a lot of things...i dont have yo put in scope but I prefer that..is this can be the problem?

Comment: It's not the problem.  The problem is `$timeout` uses `setTimeout` and 4 seconds is the minimal delay, so it's not guaranteed to be called after exactly 4 seconds. But 10 seconds is too long unless you do something that blocks the browser.

Comment: but it happens after 10 seconds, so the browser it isnt block!